# Does one pay tax for "Betrag der ausschüttungsgleichen Erträge" of an accumulating ETF in Germany?

Tags: taxes, etf, germany

There are some accumulating ETFs which may create taxable events.
Previously they were considered "tax-ugly", because it was possible to double-pay some tax. After tax reform in 2018 there is a tax-prepayment anyway, thus, this should matter less. However, this taxable event could be larger than the minimum prepayment, which I would like to avoid.

Could I estimate the amount of this tax event by "Betrag der ausschüttungsgleichen Erträge" from [bundesanzeiger](https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/ebanzwww/wexsservlet?genericsearch_param.fulltext=FR0010959676&%28page.navid%3Dto_quicksearchlist%29=Suchen) report?

Comment: Are you asking about the situation up to the fiscal year 2017, or the new situation from 2018 onwards?

Comment: The new situation from 2018.

Answer (score 1):

From 2018 onwards, that “distribution-like yield” (*ausschüttungsgleiche Erträge*) is no longer relevant, and presumably, the investment companies will stop calculating and publishing the values for their funds. Instead, only the “advance lump sum” (*Vorabpauschale*), capped to the actual performance of the fund, is relevant for tax purposes. It is calculated based on only the fund prices at the start and end of the year, and the risk-free interest rate (*Basiszins*).

Note that this taxable revenue is considered to have reached the fund owner on the first working day of the *next* year (2019 for 2018). Under the old rules, the relevant date was the last day of the *same* year (e.g. 2017). This means that holding an accumulating fund during 2018 doesn’t have any effect at all on your 2018 tax return.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your source?
I clearly remember accumulating ETFs with “distribution-like yield” > 0 were considered "tax-ugly" in 2017 and it is surprising that this changed.

Comment: @Howdedo: It’s not surprising, it’s one of the main points of the reform. :-) I’m not aware of any English-language sources, but if you read German, you can see the BVI’s [tax reform pages](https://www.bvi.de/regulierung/investmentsteuern/ueber-die-reform-2018/).